# Asymptotic Approximation of $\sum_{n_{2i-1} \ne n_{2i}}\sqrt{n_1\cdots n_k} x^{n_1 + \cdots +n_k}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, power-series, approximation

For $1\le n_i \lt \infty$ and $|x|\lt 1$, let $$S_k=\sum_{n_{2i-1} \ne n_{2i}}\sqrt{n_1\cdots n_k} x^{n_1 + \cdots +n_k}$$ I would like to find a simpler expression that is asymptotically equivalent to $S_k$ as $k\to\infty$. Since $S_k$ is a $k-$dimensional sum and has that added condition, I’m out of any good ideas. The only thought I’ve had is of squaring $S_k$, to get $$S^2_{k} = \sum_{n_{2i-1}\ne n_{2i}}n_1 \cdots n_{k} (x^2)^{n_1 +\cdots +n_k} +2S_{2k} $$ which doesn’t seem helpful. How to accomplish this task, or atleast simplify $S_k$?

Comment: What exactly are you summing over, and what is the extra condition?  I am guessing that you're taking $\sum_{n_1=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n_2=1}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{n_k=1}^{\infty}F(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$.  Is the extra constraint that $n_{2i-1} \neq n_{2i}$ for a particular value of $i$?  For all values of $i$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, that’s right. Each $n_i$ varies from $1$ to $\infty$, and $n_{2i-1} \ne n_{2i}$ for all $i\ge 1$.

Comment: Without that constraint, you just have $\sum_{n_1=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_1} x^{n_1} \sum_{n_2=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_2} x^{n_2}\cdots \sum_{n_k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_k}x^{n_k} = \left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^k$.  Which is asymptotic to $(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{k} (1-x)^{-3k/2}$ as $x\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: I imagine that the terms dropped due to the constraint make a smaller contribution.  Or are you not just interested in $x\rightarrow 1$?

Comment: @mjqxxxx $x$ is to be held constant, while $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Got it.  I was misreading the constraint... I thought it was connecting more indices together than it is.  In fact it just links $n_1$ to $n_2$, and $n_3$ to $n_4$, etc.  So the sum can be still be done exactly... I wrote a longer answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that, in the absence of the constraint that $n_{2i}\neq n_{2i-1}$ for all $i$, your $k$-dimensional sum factors into $k$ identical one-dimensional sums.  In other words, it's separable.  The result is the $k$-th power of the single sum, which can be written in terms of the polylogarithm:
$$
\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots n_k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_1 n_2\ldots n_k}x^{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k}=\sum_{n_1=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_1}x^{n_1}\sum_{n_2=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_2}x^{n_2}\cdots \sum_{n_k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_k}x^{n_k}=\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{m}x^{m}\right)^{k}=\left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^k.
$$
Now, the constraint couples every other $n_i$ to the previous one.  So in the presence of the constraint, assuming $k$ is even, the sum factors into $k/2$ identical two-dimensional sums:
$$
{\sum_{n_1,n_2,\ldots n_k=1}^{\infty}}^{\prime}\sqrt{n_1 n_2\ldots n_k}x^{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_k}=\sum_{n_1\neq n_2=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_1 n_2}x^{n_1 + n_2}\cdots \sum_{n_{k-1}\neq n_k=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n_{k-1} n_k}x^{n_{k-1}+n_k}=\left(\sum_{l\neq m=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{l m}x^{l + m}\right)^{k/2}.
$$
The two-dimensional sum is just
$$
\sum_{l\neq m=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{l m}x^{l + m}=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{lm}x^{l+m}-\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}lx^{2l}=\left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^2-{\text{Li}}^{-1}(x^2) =\left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^2-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}.
$$
And so for even $k$, the sum is exactly
$$
\left(\left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^2-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)^{k/2}.
$$
For odd $k$, you have one additional unconstrained $n_i$ being summed over, so the result in that case is exactly
$$
\left(\left({\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x)\right)^2-\frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)^{\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor} {\text{Li}}_{-1/2}(x) .
$$

Comment: There’s a problem. If that is indeed the closed form for $S_k$, then $S_k^2 = S_{2k} $ for even $k$. But using the recurrence I gave, that means $$S_k + \sum_{n_{2i-1}\ne n_{2i}} n_1 \cdots n_k (x^2)^{n_1 +\cdots n_k} =0 $$ which is clearly false. Is the recurrence wrong?

Comment: I think the recurrence is wrong... what's the justification for it?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the mistake.